# Run sideEffect only once

Tags: gremlin

I got a tiny graph like:

```
g.addV('person').property(id, 'p1').property('name', 'mark')
g.addV('person').property(id, 'p2').property('name', 'mark')
g.addV('person').property(id, 'p3').property('name', 'jack')
g.addV('person').property(id, 'p4').property('name', 'steve')

g.addE('knows').from(V('p1')).to(V('p2')).property('since', 2001)
g.addE('knows').from(V('p1')).to(V('p3')).property('since', 2010)
g.addE('knows').from(V('p2')).to(V('p3')).property('since', 2012)
g.addE('knows').from(V('p3')).to(V('p4')).property('since', 2019)
```

I wanna to submit a query to satisfy the following two demands:

- **Got all edges the 'since' of which is bigger than 2005**
- **Filter these edges, find out `inV` of which is `p1`'s friend**

As of now, I can only write the following query:

```
g.E().hasLabel('knows').has('since', gt(2005)).
    sideEffect(
    V('p1').out().aggregate('friends')).
    where(inV().where(within('friends')))
```

The result of query is as expected:

```
gremlin>     g.E().hasLabel('knows').has('since', gt(2005)).
......1>       sideEffect(
......2>       V('p1').out().aggregate('friends')).
......3>       where(inV().where(within('friends')))
==>e[26][p1-knows->p3]
==>e[27][p2-knows->p3]
```

The problem is that the `sideEffect` step runs three times, I only want to run it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sideEffect()` will run as many times as there are traversers passing through it. You can `profile()` your traversal to see what's going on there:

```
gremlin> g.E().hasLabel('knows').has('since', gt(2005)).
......1>   sideEffect(V('p1').out().aggregate('friends')).
......2>   where(inV().where(within('friends'))).profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(edge,[~label.eq(knows), since.g...                     3           3           0.180    10.58
TraversalSideEffectStep([TinkerGraphStep(vertex...                     3           3           0.859    50.48
  TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[p1])                                         3           3           0.234
  VertexStep(OUT,vertex)                                               6           6           0.134
  AggregateStep(friends)                                               6           6           0.226
TraversalFilterStep([EdgeVertexStep(IN), Profil...                     2           2           0.662    38.95
  EdgeVertexStep(IN)                                                   3           3           0.036
  WherePredicateStep(within([friends]))                                                        0.126
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           1.702        -
```

`g.E()` produces 3 traversers given your filter so three are given to the `sideEffect()` which means that step will execute three times. To get it to execute once you need to reduce those 3 to 1 - you can do that with `fold()` which will collect the three to a single list and then you unfold that list after the `sideEffect()`:

```
gremlin> g.E().hasLabel('knows').has('since', gt(2005)).
......1>   fold().
......2>   sideEffect(V('p1').out().aggregate('friends')).
......3>   unfold().
......4>   where(inV().where(within('friends'))).profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(edge,[~label.eq(knows), since.g...                     3           3           0.203    18.23
FoldStep                                                               1           1           0.072     6.52
TraversalSideEffectStep([TinkerGraphStep(vertex...                     1           1           0.329    29.54
  TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[p1])                                         1           1           0.075
  VertexStep(OUT,vertex)                                               2           2           0.061
  AggregateStep(friends)                                               2           2           0.076
UnfoldStep                                                             3           3           0.275    24.67
TraversalFilterStep([EdgeVertexStep(IN), Profil...                     2           2           0.234    21.04
  EdgeVertexStep(IN)                                                   3           3           0.032
  WherePredicateStep(within([friends]))                                                        0.066
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -           1.115
```

So, I think that's the direct answer to your question. If I'm digging a bit deeper I would wonder if you had a reason for the complexity you are describing here. If you want to find the edges that represent incoming edges to the friends of "p1" that are after "2005" then I think that's accomplished by:

```
gremlin> g.V('p1').out('knows').inE('knows').has('since',gt(2005))
==>e[5][p1-knows->p3]
==>e[6][p2-knows->p3]
```

Comment: Yes, I may mention the size of dataset I used. As the gremlin service I used provides index on 'since' property of edge 'knows', and there are 1M edges, after filter by '2015', there are about 10k. The number of 'friends' is around 300, so I think it's better if I can take advantage of the edge property index.

Comment: what graph are you using that supports edge index lookups that way?

Comment: I used [Alibaba Graph Database](https://cn.aliyun.com/product/gdb) which supports property index by default.

Comment: interesting - not sure i can think of another graph that does global index lookups like that